# Log4j settings, not showing logs for my package

Tags: log4j

I am trying to get my log4j property working, I messed it up I think.

```
log4j.rootLogger=ALL
log4j.appender.CA=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ddMMMyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-4r [%t] %-5p %c{1} %x - %m%n
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=ERROR
log4j.debug=TRUE
log4j.logger.net.spy.memcached=ERROR
log4j.logger.com.mcruiseon.server=ALL
```

My package is **com.mcruiseon.server**

Comment: What is loglevel ALL? Shouldn't that be rather something like INFO or DEBUG? Plus, shouldn't your logger setting pick a suitable appender?

Comment: Will this work ? log4j.rootLogger=INFO, ConsoleAppender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try something like this:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, CA
log4j.logger.com.mcruiseon.server=INFO, CA
log4j.additivity.com.mcruiseon.server=false

log4j.appender.CA=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ddMMMyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-4r [%t] %-5p %c{1} %x - %m%n
```

This does: define a CA console logger, tell rootLogger to log ERROR and above to CA, define a logger for your package that logs INFO and above to CA, and sets its additivity to false to prevent messages from appearing in more than one appender (which is no issue here since you only have CA, but will become one once you route your logger to its own file appender).